# How to use non-ascii characters in the regex filter of the declarativeNetRequest API for a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension but just found out that it's not possible to use non-ascii characters in the [regex filter](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#property-RuleCondition-regexFilter) of the declarativeNetRequest API. Which I need because I want to use it to match and block all requests to domains with TLD **рф** and **дети**. Is there any solution for this?

I currently use a block action in a ruleset specified with the following condition and this works fine:

```
"condition": {"regexFilter": "^(.*):\/\/(.*).(ru|su|tatar)\/(.*)", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
```

However, I still want to add TLDs **рф** and **дети**. I tried using a Unicode-encoded representation  of that in the regex too but it also didn't work. So, how to use non-ascii characters in the regex filter of the declarativeNetRequest API for a Google Chrome extension? Or is there an alternative approach to achieve this?

***Side-note:** I feel like this question belongs more the "Web Applications" Stack Exchange, however considering the tag google-chrome-extensions has [27.000+ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) on StackOverflow and [less than 100 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extensions) on WebApps Stack Exchange I think it's more effective to post it here .*

Comment: Do you mean to say `"^([^/]*)://([^/]*)[.](ru|su|tatar|дети|рф)/(.*)"` does not work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. And the Unicode encoded variant of `дети|рф` also doesn't work in the regex.

Comment: You mean `"^([^/]*)://([^/]*)[.](ru|su|tatar|\u0434\u0435\u0442\u0438|\u0440\u0444)/(.*)"`? Did you also try `"^([^/]*)://([^/]*)[.](ru|su|tatar|\\u0434\\u0435\\u0442\\u0438|\\u0440\\u0444)/(.*)"`?

Comment: Thanks. I noticed some other changes to your regex too. However, yes that's what I meant and I just tried your version too and it doesn't work either. Same error. `rules.json: Rule with id 1 specifies an incorrect value for the "regexFilter" key. Could not load manifest.`

Comment: It does not make sense now. There must be some bug or another issue as `\uXXXX` is a valid hex notation in ECMAScript flavor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was exactly my thought. That's why I opened this question to begin with.

Comment: No, the documentation says "Use punycode encoding for internationalized domains".

Comment: You're a lifesaver, I missed that. Converted using https://www.punycoder.com/. In my regex I now use `(ru|su|tatar|xn--p1ai|xn--d1acj3b)` and I can confirm this works for дети and рф. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So for the sake of completeness. As user wOxxOm mentioned in the comments of the question. Punycode is the solution in cases of internationalized domains.

So in order to match the TLDs **рф** and **детиI** I used this regex instead:

```
^(.*):\/\/(.*).(ru|su|tatar|xn--p1ai|xn--d1acj3b)\/(.*)
```

I converted it to Punycode using, https://www.punycoder.com/.